# Lovasz theta and circulant graphs

Tags: graph-theory, it.information-theory, coding-theory, semidefinite-programming, circulant-matrices

Let $\theta(G)$ denote Shannon zero error capacity of graph $G$ and $\vartheta(G)$ be Lovasz upper bound for $\theta(G)$.

Let $C_{2n+1}$ denote cycle graph with $2n+1$ nodes.

We know following two things:

1. $$\theta(C_{2n+1})\leq \vartheta(C_{2n+1})=\frac{n\cdot \cos(\frac\pi n)}{1+\cos(\frac\pi n)}$$
2. $$\theta(C_5)=\vartheta(C_5)=\sqrt{5}$$

Let $\mathcal{Circ_n}$ be a collection of all circulant graphs on $n$ vertices. Naturally $C_n\in\mathcal{Circ_n}$.

Other than for $C_n$ is there any other class of $G\in\mathcal{Circ_n}$ for which exact expression of $\vartheta(G)$ is known?

Comment: There are some further results, in particular for circulant graphs of degree four, in this paper: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-46521-9_24

Comment: Powers of cycle graphs: https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0444. Also, note that for vertex transitive graphs, which include circulants, the product of Loavsz theta for the graph and its complement is equal to the number of vertices, so knowing the value for the graph determines the value for the complement. Also, if the graph is vertex and edge transitive, then Lovasz theta of the complement is equal to 1 - (\lambda_max/\lambda_min) where \lambda_max is the max eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix, and \lambda_min is the min eigenvalue.

Comment: @DavidE.Roberson can you please give the references for "Also, if the graph is vertex and edge transitive, then Lovasz theta of the complement is equal to 1 - (\lambda_max/\lambda_min) where \lambda_max is the max eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix, and \lambda_min is the min eigenvalue. "?

Comment: @Turbo This is more or less Theorem 9 of Lovasz' original paper: http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/theta.pdf. You can weaken the assumption to being 1-walk-regular, and I think this was first proven here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.5545.pdf. Note that that paper refers to 1-walk-regular graphs as 1-homogeneous graphs.

Comment: @DavidE.Roberson is form here on right track https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81745/is-this-general-form-of-lovasz-theta-function-of-circulant-graphs?

Comment: @Turbo I don't honestly know, I haven't thought very hard about it. As Dima pointed out in your earlier post, for a circulant graph (or any graph that is the union of classes in a symmetric association scheme) the Lovasz theta function is equal to the value of a linear program. This linear program will be closely related to the eigenvalues of the graph, but I would be somewhat surprised if there were a closed form expression for this value for circulants, though it may be possible. You could check your expression against the powers of the cycle graphs from that first link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

$\vartheta(G_p)=\sqrt{p}$ if $G_p$ is the Paley graph of order $p$

Comment: By what is written in the comments, the following more general statement is true: if $G$ is vertex-transitive and self-complementary (as the Paley graphs are), then $\theta(G)=\sqrt n$ where $n$ is the number of vertices.

Comment: Can you add a reference or details about why this is true?